# I wrote a function for the select part of the material table

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote a function for the select part of the material table, but for some reason my function doesn't run

```html
        <ng-container matColumnDef="select" sticky>
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="px-2 w-50px">
            <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" color="warn"
                [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                [attr.aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index" class="px-2 w-50px">
            <mat-checkbox (click)="selectRow($event, i)" color="warn"
                (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                [attr.aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
            </mat-checkbox>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
```

```
  selectRow(event: any, index: number) {
    console.log('event', index, event);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

I just want to run this code, but nothing happens when I click.
The other function I run within this is the selected function of the material table. What could be the problem with why my code doesn't run when I click?

Comment: Is there any difference between `(change)` and `(click)`? I could see the `(change)` Event cancelling any `(click)`events.

Comment: Which part deletes the click run?